# UIIMagePickerController don't automatically dismiss picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

How do you prevent the UIImagePickerController from automatically dismissing the camera after a picture is taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the picker to `allowsImageEditing` to be `YES` before you present it.

```
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```